# Apply Function to All Tables in same Div with ID - jQuery Show/Hide

Tags: jquery, css

I have a pretty simple problem with a lot of markup to navigate around. I've uploaded a file that has everything in the same .html for review. It's way too long to post here (markup @ 1500 lines), but I can give line # key notes.

http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

jQuery:

```
<script>
    (function() { 

       $('tr.catTr td').not('.category').hover(function () {

            var priceSel = $(this).index();

            $('tr.priceRow td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
            $('tr.priceRow2 td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
            $('tr.catTr td:nth-child(' + (priceSel + 1) + ')').addClass('vertFilt');
            $(this).parent('tr').find('td.category').addClass('category_hover');
            $(this).parent('tr').find('td').not('.category').addClass('rowHov');

        }, function () {
            var priceSel = $(this).index();
            $('tr.priceRow td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('price_hover');
            $('tr.priceRow2 td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('price_hover');
            $('td.vertFilt').removeClass('vertFilt');
            $(this).parent('tr').find('td.category').removeClass('category_hover');
            $(this).parent('tr').find('td').removeClass('rowHov');
       });

})();
</script>
```

The problem appears to be that my function specifically for the vertical highlighting **(Desktop / Laptop / Server)**, as well as my secondary highlight on the bottom, is only functioning for the **Drop Off** page.

Let me give my theory at the moment...

Every table has an ID of 'prices':
4 in total, lines:
348, 541, 735, 968
. My CSS breaks the horizontal positioning if I make it a class instead of an ID.

I've been under the impression that multiple ID's are OK, as long as only one is visible at a time: ex: http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/contact.html

**Is this the reason that only the first page is highlighting the upper and lowered hovered systems or is something else at play?**

Is there something I could fix here to only target the visible table?

```
var priceSel = $(this).index();
        $('tr.priceRow td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
        $('tr.priceRow2 td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
```

Yet again:

http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

Comment: It's invalid in HTML to give the same ID to more than one element. **Even** when only one of those elements is visible.

Comment: You`re missusing the ID, an id is an identifier, an unique identifier, there should never be more than one item with the same ID

Comment: ******** UPDATE:
Setting classes to each table didn't work.
Is this an initial loading DOM issue?

Comment: "Setting classes to each table didn't work." You most definitely can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    (function() { 

       $('tr.catTr td').not('.category').hover(function () {

            var priceSel = $(this).index();
            console.log(priceSel);
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr.priceRow td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr.priceRow2 td').eq(priceSel).addClass('price_hover');
            $('tr.catTr td:nth-child(' + (priceSel + 1) + ')').addClass('vertFilt');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td.category').addClass('category_hover');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not('.category').addClass('rowHov');

        }, function () {
            var priceSel = $(this).index();
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr.priceRow td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('price_hover');
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr.priceRow2 td').eq(priceSel).removeClass('price_hover');
            $('td.vertFilt').removeClass('vertFilt');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td.category').removeClass('category_hover');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td').removeClass('rowHov');
       });

})();
</script>
```

**Resolves the Issue**